# What are the time and space complexities of this powerset function?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity, powerset

Hello I have been practicing algorithms and data structures, and I solved https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/ which is the powerset function but it appears my solution is too slow.
Here is the code:

```
def subsets(array):
    set = [array]
    n = len(array)
    for i in range(n):
        tmp_subsets = subsets(array[:i] + array[i+1:])
        for subset in tmp_subsets:
            if subset not in set:
                set.append(subset)
    return set
```

I know there are other better/faster solutions but I am trying to understand the time and space complexities of this one.

I think time complexity here is `O(n^n)` since the recursion tree has `n` branches per level and `n` levels total is it correct ?

So it is worse than the optimal `O(2^n)` solution.

I am not sure of space complexity though, my instincts say `O(2^n)` but when I draw out the recursion tree it's a little confusing because the space I am using at the point where my recursion stack is the biggest is:

```
space_for_level(0)+space_for_level(1)+...+space_for_level(n)
n + (n-1) +...+ 1 = O(n^2)
```

But in the end when I return everything the size of `set` is `O(2^n)` so my space complexity would be `O(2^n + n^2) = O(2^n)`.

Is my analysis correct for both time and space ? Any pointers to help me think in a clearer way are welcome.

Comment: it is exponential in time and space

Comment: the exact form of the exponential performance needs the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) to be applied

Comment: But that's the thing in this case the recurrence is `T(n) = nT(n-1)` and the theorem does not apply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Time complexity**

The time complexity can be summed up to the following recurrence relation:

`T(n) = n * T(n-1) + n * 2^(n-1)`

since there is a main loop running `n` times and each time the subsets of the remaining elements (`n-1`) are **first generated (`T(n-1)`)** and **then looped over (`2^(n-1)`)**.

**note** the relation assumes every other *operation in the loop takes constant time*, which is a reasonable approximation as its effects as `n` grows are minimal. For example this operation:

```
if subset not in set
```

**does not** take constant time (it takes linear time in the list length, also `set.append(subset)` is not constant time in general), but lets overlook it for now (you get the picture and how to analyse the code).

The recurrence relation suggests a complexity **at least exponential**.

**Space complexity**

First of all, all subsets of `n` are generated, this means at least a complexity of `O(2^n)`. However due to recursion and re-generation of subsets during each step the space complexity is more than that. Specificaly in each loop step one running copy of subsets of `n-1` are generated and then augmented to the original subsets. We have:

`S(n) = S(n-1) + 2^n`

since each call to subset generates `1` intermediate running copy of the **remaining subsets (i.e `S(n-1)`)** plus it **combines those into the original subsets which are `2^n`**.

**note** we do not count the storage needed to store each item of the subsets set, which itself requires a storage of complexity around `O(n)`, but consider this to be of constant storage of `O(1)` for simplicity (for example storing a subset as a word, in binary encoding, for small `n <= 64`) so the whole storage of the subsets (without counting auxiliary storage) would be simply of `O(2^n)` complexity (else, as noted in comment, the storage complexity to simply store all subsets of `n` is of `O(n 2^n)` order).

The recurrence relation suggests a complexity **at least exponential**.

**Solution**

Since the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) cannot be applied for these recurrence relations (as noted), check [methods for solving first-order recurrence relations with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients) in order to solve above relations (space complexity is like an arithmetic progression, while time complexity has more complex form) and acquire exact form of complexity (although the solution  might be very complex and it will still be exponential one way or the other)

**Better complexity**

**Better time and space complexity can be achieved by exploiting the structure and properties of subsets** (given a definite ordering, eg *lexicographic*).

Specifically the intimate relationship an already generated subset has to its predecessor and successor. So the successor (the next subset in sequence) can be **generated with only minimal changes made to its predecessor** (e.g adding or removing only a single element).

For example the **code generates many duplicates** which it then tests if they already exist, this **can be avoided** all-together. Plus the recursion is not needed, so the time and space complexity of recursion can be eliminated. Furthermore only **constant storage is needed inside the main loop** (given that next subset can be generated with only minimal, constant amount of changes made to previous subset) and so on. All these optimisations exploit in one way or the other the symmetries and properties of the subsets under a definite ordering.

PS. You can also research similar questions on [computer.science.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-complexity) which is involved with algorithmic complexity more fully

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights. I think your analysis of time complexity is spot on and very helpful. However I am a bit confused when it comes to space complexity. Are you saying `S(n) = S(n-1) + 2^n` where  `2^n` corresponds to `set` and `S(n-1)` corresponds to `tmp_subsets`. If that's so can't we just say `S(n-1) = S(n-2) + 2^(n-1) ... S(1) = S(0) + 2` --> `S(n) = O(2^n)`.

Comment: Another way would be to look at the recursion tree and figure out when the program uses the most space and that does not happen before we start backtracking and `set` starts getting closer to '2^n' and so the time where we use the most memory is when we are doing `for subset in tmp_subsets:` for the last time and that means both `set` and `tmp_subsets` are `O(2^n)` --> `S(n) = O(2^n)`. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Don't all subsets of `[1,...,n]` take O(n2^(n-1)) space?

Comment: @d_darric, the space complexity is as stated, because the code uses a temporary storage of `S(n-1)` to generate the temporary `n-1` subsets plus the `2^n` storage required to return all current subsets. One can try to say that `S(n-1)` is simply `2^(n-1)` but this is not so, since it recursively requires more space to generate the temporary `S(n-2)` subsets and so on.. In any case one can solve the recurrence relation and acquire the exact form of complexity which (without solving it) I presume is of `O(n 2^n)` order.

Comment: @xskxzr, sure that would be so counting the storage of an item of the subsets set as well. Which in this case we assume it takes constant storage `O(1)` for simplicity (updated answer to reflect this assumption)

Comment: @xskxzr they do but the thing is they never all exist at the same time and that's what's at the heart of my confusion. Since space complexity is defined as the point at which the program uses the most space and I am having trouble identifying that.

Comment: @NikosM. I get why you say `S(n) = O(n 2^n)` in my first comment that is what I meant to write and it is easily obtainable from the recursive relation you give `S(n) = S(n-1) + 2^n`. Where I still need to improve is the ability to derive that equation from looking at the code. So your reasoning is: the space I need now `S(n)` is the max space of my current `set` which is `2^n` + the space I need for one of the `S(n-1)` in the loop since we have at most one `S(n-1)` alive on the stack at a given time. And once you have that equation solving it by substitution is trivial... thx again

Comment: @d_darric,exactly, this is my analysis for space complexity

Comment: @NikosM. ok cool that makes sense, we usually never care for analysis of the time/space complexities once they are classified as exponential when solving interview problems. But in this case it made sense to push it further thx again.

Comment: @d_darric, hope that helped you, check my updated answer for hints to achieve better complexity as well

Comment: @NikosM. This may not have been your intention, but please do not suggest people to crosspost, as we generally [do not want crossposts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Suggesting another site for a reformulation or follow-up question is of course fine, as long as this does result in unnecessary cross-site duplication. Thank you!

Comment: @Discretelizard, thank for letting me know, updated answer to rephrase that section. Cheers!